# Tracking All Instances While Preserving Const Correctness

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, const-correctness

There are situations where tracking all instances of a class in a container is desirable. There are existing discussions about this on Stack Exchange (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16501419/11155375), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41644086/11155375), [3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/171631/256318)). While dealing with this on my own, I realized that automatically registering instances in a container is prone to undermine const correctness.

This is due to the fact that during construction the `this` pointer is always considered to be non-const. As far as I know, there is no way to determine whether the currently constructed instance is declared constant or not. Consider this (minimal) example, which compiles fine and succeeds with writing `555` to `inst1` without even flinching:

```
#include <forward_list>

template <typename TInstance>
class ObjList
{
public:
    ObjList()
    {
        instances().push_front(static_cast<TInstance*>(this));
    }

    // Guard against SIOF
    static std::forward_list<TInstance*>& instances()
    {
        static std::forward_list<TInstance*> instances;
        return instances;
    }
};

class SomeClass : public ObjList<SomeClass>
{
public:
    SomeClass(int someData) :
        someData{someData}
    {}

    void write(int data)
    {
        someData = data;
    }

private:
    int someData;
};

SomeClass inst0{200};
const SomeClass inst1{400};

int main()
{
    for (SomeClass* instance : ObjList<SomeClass>::instances())
    {
        instance->write(555);
    }
}
```

Or the more extensive example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAKykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAA7AAcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4BaRlZAqHhUSyx8cm2mPaOAkIETMQEuT5%2BgXaYDtmNzQSlkTFxiSkKTS1t%2BZ0TA2FDFSPJAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMYcjeWADUJrtu/MQA7s3oAPq0eONn2CYaAIJ7B0eYp%2BfI43QWCoLzenzM%2BwYhy8JzObic42ImFYoI%2BXyhPz%2BFxILCYBFRnw%2BBEwLFSBmJWIIAE9UoxWL8ACoASQY40MWwJhyYCgUxwA8tFtKFnmiElYPqkvNFHsgQGDjgr%2BYLhQQIJkAF6YO4EY54dDLY5yj6Kk269AmMV6i0AEXliot4vepsVYTZUMwCggywAdJKFAg7lRiLI1U1HMg7qJnudmaymu6AFQvCAEBBPZbLM6Ok02sF2hUarU64CYAhM9Be/OnMVVk1IggbBhmrNV3No42KgD0neOAHEvLdjkxgExXTqhEy%2BQAxKts8PHQEgECXG7Ee6PaNuWNurZJ3avMwANl1cfZHsrHYVDtrirneGQC4I6CXK9uDye%2BJjLJ3mD32BPP4KC2l6mvWjYAfGWxAbs2b2gktrtu8qTBsSDiYM%2BVYAH4CkKH4Xk6cGwc6Y5np6PpIiwqAAG6YKGeL3pG3Kflu36Qb%2ByapummYwa28F5hKxB4FReLsLOeCatqzY8aKtrSYS7xcjyxxCKgbBuAYSkgMckrSveSq4ZuKlqRp0GvKKjo6TKRoEQqRmYOp3KeoWkl6qQJ46goqmYNaeJMAa1nOgqOEqg6VrwaQN4Fl5PlNA6nlsDFTBtjZ1ZWHxiEmmEOpIkwFYGmgca8URoGluB8Xeb5wEpclVZUagerHFcgnEhAWXHOgvmZiB14gSa5WJX81rtZVck5ul8nIUJIkBS6ggLtFI2OrmclgnZDlKWOGgOhoblmBoW18XJa0mRBXAOlwbm7Pty2OgV4zKV5628mOZgOmYbmSNdh1LR8bW4mE%2BE9Sli4oOsOpwnCpxmGYABKyLoMcDIevi0NYpDIOuLQVUmpcxwQMdjkJhBZ6GvpIXnATPIvEuJHumRXXVTWvW3k%2BS5oF44PnJDj7PsuOJ4hA5hmEy1padefH%2BG4OqJXKNZ8dDbm01sAC0LwlmWeWK6e7qq/uOV5QaEPnDzS6Y9jcEIfJfWs6DHNo8bQsAOrNYyyNC/bbgmyAZujYquP449JlE0rvxacFH5wpTpk09rUFegzY3FZlseYLr2BNYQtH%2BNn3FJyzvPs5zbjcyDly4qqQsi2Lcu2pL0u%2BbLaW2grxM62rpbll6Ws/mn%2Bvxx7Xs%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%2BHejMHjXAhASAoK4MsXg1CtAZlILg/w%2BDOBENIOEvFpAIFQMBeQyh6DMGrHoUwsGkoCDsIgJw1IrDiARHpJwEFYKIVQphccOFZheDoWRRMvQ6ThCiHEDkyV%2BS1AkOKaQJqTBUgRP0H80lJDAV8g5oy44qAqDAtBeCyF0LYW7HhXjDwXC4iovRdSmh2Lj65RGF3AhhLiU7TJaMshtgqWYqwTivBGqOC7H%2BeSv1gbsUEOFVqgFUaaWrBoiI7IIBJBAA%3D%3D). Others have pointed out that this is just another way to shoot yourself into the foot and a source of undefined behavior (see [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40294063/11155375)).

The primary questions are:

- Is there a way to fix this?
- Can you recommend me a different design to look into?

  - Note: Unlike the example on godbolt, I must use C++14.

If there is no way to fix this, I am even OK with the fact that users can modify instances that have been *declared* constant via a detour (there is going to be documentation on the topic). The remaining question is then:

- If I enforce that all instances are put in a writable memory location (e.g. through adding a `mutable` member in `ObjList`), can I continue to use the outlined approach or will this still result in undefined behavior?

Comment: You could maybe reverse the logic: instead of inheritance, do `ObjList<const SomeClass> inst1;`. `ObjList` constructs `SomeClass`, and also knows if it is const. Of course, simply creating a new `SomeClass` instance then no longer registers itself, but maybe this is ok in your use cases? You could also make its constructor private and a friend of `ObjList` to force usage of `ObjList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I enforce that all instances are put in a writable memory location (e.g. through adding a mutable member in ObjList), can I continue to use the outlined approach or will this still result in undefined behavior?

[[dcl.type.cv]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4) states that you may modify mutable members of const objects but modifying const members is undefined behaviour.

> Can you recommend me a different design to look into?

You could force instances of your classes to be mutable by declaring them as members of a wrapper class rather than as derived classes.

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper
{
private:
    mutable T value;

public:
    static std::forward_list<T*>& instances()
    {
        static std::forward_list<T*> instances;
        return instances;
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    explicit Wrapper(Args&&... args)
    : value(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
        instances().push_front(&value);
    }

    Wrapper(Wrapper const&) = delete;
    Wrapper& operator=(Wrapper const&) = delete;

    T const& get() const { return value; }
    T& get() { return value; }
};
```

You could make the constructor of the wrapped class private to force the use of `Wrapper<T>`.

```
class SomeClass
{
    friend class Wrapper<SomeClass>;

private:
    SomeClass(int);
};
```